# Doing a SQLite MATCH using only negated terms

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, full-text-search

I recently found that this is impossible in SQLite:

```
 SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE fruit MATCH '-apple'
```

Yet this is possible:

```
 SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE fruit MATCH 'pear -apple'
```

I tried this using FTS3 and FTS4 with the same results. Why does match require at least one non-negated term? And how do I work around this limitation? I need to return all fruits that don't match "apple"...that's it. Any ideas?

Comment: `c` tag removed. Why was it there in the first place? ?!?!?!?!

Comment: I'm using the native C API for SQLite and included it in case it was an issue specific to that. I'm okay with you removing it but please calm down.

Comment: Maybe I overdid it with the question marks and exclamation marks :) but my question was in good faith. Answers to your question may be better if it is known why c is relevant. Suggestion: add that information to the body of your question (and a c tag if you really feel it is helpful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM fruit 
WHERE fruit.oid NOT IN 
(
    SELECT oid FROM fruit WHERE fruit MATCH 'apple'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Why don't you simply invert the search?</strike>

```
select * from fruit where fruit NOT match 'apple'
```

You could use a EXCEPT clause:

```
select * from fruit except select * from fruit where fruit match 'apple';
```

but that might not be very efficient.

Comment: That syntax doesn't work. SQL logic error or missing database: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context.